# Use regexp inSQL/PL for no repetitions in digits

Tags: sql, sqlplus, regexp-substr, regexp-like, xregexp

**I have a table below and need to use a  regular expression to display the correct course digits ( 3 digits being the max # of digits) and also max sure no number appears twice.**

[image]

the following code I have created is this:

```
select regexp_substr(course_number,'([0-9][0-9][0-9])\1') as CourseNumber
```

from courses
/

this is correct showing me an output of this:

[image]

**How can I sure the regexp in sql/pl to query the digits with no numbers repeating?**

the table I created looks like this:

[image]

Comment: There's no such thing as "sql/pl". Also the question doesn't seem to need SQL\*Plus or JavaScript. Did you mean Oracle SQL?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the sample data and desired output as text, not images. What is the expected output for `'EE  2001'`?